# Possible issues in NHibernate CreateSQLQuery

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Are there restrictions/problems when using CreateSQLQuery? Should we avoid using CreateSQLQuery, or is it okay to use it in some special cases? What happens with the hibernate -cache, I think hibernate doesn't get this kind of changes?

Comment: You're asking if NHibernate parses the string passed to `CreateSQLQuery` so that it can maintain statefulness? ... I'd say no..

Comment: I'm not sure how Hibernate handles database calls internally, I think Hibernate has something like an cache and if I use SQL I invalidate the cache ... so maby something bad happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use CreateSQLQuery as a last resort as it bypasses most the functionality NHibernate provides. It's effectively an ADO.NET call in the middle of your ORM system.

In addition you lose the benefit of NHibernate generating your SQL (and so making it database independent).

If possible try creating a [HQL](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/queryhql.html) query instead.

Comment: Is database independence the only advantage?